# How can I do this layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpOdqJ)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/16q2/667343/2016-ford-focus-rs-vs-subaru-wrx-sti-vw-golf-r-comparison-test-car-and-driver-photo-667344-s-original.jpg" alt="car1" title="car1" />
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      details
    </div>   
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
body{
  background:black;
}
.container{
  background:#f3f4f6;
  border-bottom:5px solid #db5207;
}
.image-container,.desc{
   display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.desc{
  background:red;
}
img{
  width:612px;
  height:412px;
  border:10px solid white
}
```

I put an image to better understand what they want to do

[image]

basically I want the image to be over container and divul "desc" to be by end.

You can help me solve this problem? What is the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this here code it may be solve your problem

```css
 *{margin:0;padding:0;}
.container{margin:100px 0;height:200px;border:5px solid red;position:relative;}
.image-container{height:300px;width:30%;border:5px solid blue;position:absolute;right:55%;top:-30%;}
.image-container img{height:300px;width:100%;}
.desc-container{height:190px;width:50%;border:5px solid green;float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/16q2/667343/2016-ford-focus-rs-vs-subaru-wrx-sti-vw-golf-r-comparison-test-car-and-driver-photo-667344-s-original.jpg" alt="car1" title="car1" />
    </div>
    <div class="desc-container">
      details
    </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code for your answer. Also you can verify the codepen https://codepen.io/sasikumarhx/pen/VKmQod

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/16q2/667343/2016-ford-focus-rs-vs-subaru-wrx-sti-vw-golf-r-comparison-test-car-and-driver-photo-667344-s-original.jpg" alt="car1" title="car1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="desc">
      details
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  background:black;
}
.container{
  background:#f3f4f6;
  border:5px solid #db5207;
  height:250px;

}
.right{
  float:right;
  width:49%;
}
.left{
  float:left;
  width:49%;
}
.image-container{
}
.desc{
  background:red;
}
img{
  width:50%;
  height:130%;
  border:10px solid white;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: the image must go out of the container (please look at the picture of my drawing position)
Also they should not use fixed width for divs .left and .right

Answer (score 0):

please check below code:

just need to change in css:

```
body{
  background:black;
}
.container{
  background:#f3f4f6;
  border-bottom:5px solid #db5207;

  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 380px

}
.image-container,.desc{
   display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;

}
.desc{
  background:red;
  min-height: 380px;

  display: inline-block;

}
img{
  width:612px;
  height:412px;
  border:10px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: its just answer of "John Smith" question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following if it satisfies your requirement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Solution</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        #container {
            background-color: #DCDCDC;
            position: relative;
            left: 100px;
            top: 100px;
            width: 800px;
            height: 200px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #image {
            background-color: #F0E68C;
            width: 200px;
            height: 255px;
            position: relative;
            left: 150px;
            top: -80px;
        }

        #details {
            background-color: #FF7F50;
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            left: 380px;
            top: -310px;
            height: 190px;
        }

        h2 {
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
            <h2>container</h2>
        <div id="image">
            <h2>image</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="details">
            <h2>details</h2>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```